# MAX TO_DATE OVER two IDs of an IF statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I’m using the this query to connect with amazon redshift.

And I have the following query:

```
Select b.*, c."releasedate",
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.originboardid ORDER BY TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(b.sprintenddate,0,9), 'DD/Mon/YY') DESC) AS "rank_sprint",
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.originboardid ORDER BY TO_DATE(c.releasedate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DESC) AS "rank_release",
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b.issueid, b.sprintid DESC) as "rank_issue",
MAX(IF (b.issueorigin='completed') AND (b.changeto='In Progress') and (b.changefield='status')
    max(TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(b.changecreation,0,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')) OVER(b.issueid,b.sprintid)
) OVER (b.issueid,b.sprintid) as "lastinprogress"
from digitalplatforms.issues_braze b

Left join jira.releases c
On b.version_id=c.versionid
```

and its outputing the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "max" 
Position: 459;
```

Also if I query just:

```
Select b.*, c.“releasedate”,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.originboardid ORDER BY TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(b.sprintenddate,0,9), ‘DD/Mon/YY’) DESC) AS “rank_sprint”,
DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY b.originboardid ORDER BY TO_DATE(c.releasedate, ‘YYYY-MM-DD’) DESC) AS “rank_release”,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b.issueid, b.sprintid DESC) as “rank_issue”
from digitalplatforms.issues_braze b

Left join jira.releases c
On b.version_id=c.versionid
```

it works.

Can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is no "IF" statement in SQL.  SQL is not procedural.  You need to rewrite you query using "CASE" or "DECODE" statements.

Also you cannot nest window functions.  If you logic requires this then these need to operate at different levels of the query (SELECT level).  However, are you sure both of these need to window functions - MAX() OVER vs. MAX()?  They are using the same OVER clause so I expect not.

Just guessing based on you query but does this give you what you want?

```
MAX(DECODE((b.issueorigin='completed') AND (b.changeto='In Progress') and (b.changefield='status')), true,
    TO_DATE(SUBSTRING(b.changecreation,0,10),'YYYY-MM-DD')
) OVER (b.issueid,b.sprintid) as "lastinprogress"
```